# How do I insert text in an sql database using the new Jdatabase system?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling with this for the entire morning. Here is the code (to be precise the $message variable is defined with $message= htmlspecialchars($_GET["message"]); :

```
 if (!$user->guest)
{
    if (!$message=="")
    { 
    echo $message;
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->INSERT('#__soccermanager_chats (userid,message,eventid) VALUES ('.$user->id.','.$message.','.$gameid.')');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();
    }
}
```

Basically all it does is adding a message to a message board. The only thing is that it's only working with figures and not letters.

So I have been looking to my mysql table and the message field type is varchar(255). And when I do a manuel query from eskuel it works!

Comment: Must every php mysql question have an SQL-injection hole?

Comment: Can you tell me where the SQL-injection is please ?

Comment: `('.$user->id.','.$message.','.$gameid.')` has much potential for it. In each of the variables, there can be something nasty - except you have prepared them before already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Php u can assign variable using "$variable name"
for Example $number=1(integer)$string="a"(String)$float=1.23(float)
u want to insert number through variable u can use  '.$number.' and if u want to insert String then u can use '".$string."'.
$query->INSERT('#__soccer manager_chats (user id,message,event id) VALUES ('.$user->id.','".$message."','.$game id.')');

Comment: @user1007015 - if you have an answer that solves your problem you can thank the person who helped you by clicking the "tick" icon to mark his answer as "accepted".